# jQuery Superfish menu and SEO

Tags: jquery, seo, superfish

I'm using a Superfish menu in a sidebar that shows its child menu options dynamically on hover. For various reasons, I need to create the child/submenu elements dynamically which is creating an issue for "crawlability" and good SEO.

Anyone have some ideas on how to overcome this obstacle? I'm concerned that creating the submenu options on page load and simply hiding them until hovered would create an SEO mess, but I need those links to be reachable by search bots when the page is crawled and also to create good sitemaps.

Thanks!

CODE USED FOR DYNAMIC SUBMENU:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id;
var visits = 0;
var arrCounties = ["cities1.txt","cities2.txt","cities3.txt","cities4.txt","cities5.txt","cities6.txt","cities7.txt","cities8.txt","cities9.txt"];

var page = "-page-url.aspx";

for(id=0;id<arrCounties.length;id++){

    $('#smItem_'+id).append("<ul id='submenu_"+id+"' class='seo_submenu'></ul>");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/COUNTIES/"+arrCounties[id],
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var cities = data.split("\r\n");

            for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
                var cName = cities[i].substr(0,cities[i].indexOf(','));
                cName = cName.replace(/\s+/g,'-');

                $('#submenu_'+id).append("<li class='current'><a class='cityLinks' href='http://www.domain.com/location/" + cName + page + "'>"+cities[i]+"</a></li>");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the links are in the plain HTML source. Then there is no harm done from the SEO perspective at all.

Edit:
Adding links with JavaScript in the browser is not good for crawl-ability, adding them with your server side programming language is ok. Doesn't matter much that they are hidden as far as they are in the plain HTML that the server returns.

Comment: OK... Maybe I should rephrase my question:

I need to edit Superfish so the submenu items are generated on page load and are only hidden but not totally removed from the HTML. Currently, the submenu items don't exist until the mouseover event creates them, then they disappear totally on mouseout.

So, how do I edit Superfish to load them and only hide them from view until the mouseover event so they can still be crawled?

Comment: It's best if you would show the code that you use to generate the submenu.

Comment: That's not good Greg, search engines have no way to crawl it, you need to redo it using the backend code. The answer I gave you still applies. You can't do that in JavaScript. It will be crawled if you put the links in your HTML and XML sitemap, but the internal link architecture will be very poor.